# Splitting multiple dots in a list into multiple single dots

Tags: python, list

I got list that looks like this

```
list=[Item0,'.','.','.','...','.',Item1,'.','.']
```

What is the most efficient way how to divide the "...", so the list looks like this

```
list=[Item0,'.','.','.','.','.','.','.',Item1,'.','.']
```

I tried this, but i know it's not efficient at all.

```
for n,sign in enumerate(list):
        if ".." in sign:
            list[n]="."
            list.insert(n+1,".")
            list.insert(n + 2,".")
```

Comment: That list isn't valid Python syntax. Is it a single string? Is it a list containing strings?

Comment: What should happen if one of the items in the list is a string `'a..b'`?

Comment: @tobias_k it's list of strings

Comment: Can there be various lengths of dots, like `'..'`, `'....'`, `'.......'`, or is it always exactly three dots?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Nothing, dots should be changing only if there are multiple dots as single item and there can be multiple dots

Comment: Also, maybe you could explain where you get that list from and what you are trying to achieve with the resulting list. Maybe there is a better approach altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested ist comprehension, checking whether `all` the characters in the strings (assuming all the items are strings) are `.` and then iterating the individual characters, otherwise taking the item itself.

```
>>> Item0, Item1 = "Item0", "Item1"
>>> lst = [Item0,'.','.','.','...','.',Item1,'.','.']
>>> [y for x in lst for y in (x if all(c=='.' for c in x) else [x])]
['Item0', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'Item1', '.', '.']
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
import re

l = ['.', '...', 'Item1']

new_l = []
for i in l:
    if re.fullmatch(r'\.{2,}', i):
        new_l.extend(j for j in i)
    else:
        new_l.append(i)

print(new_l)
# ['.', '.', '.', '.', 'Item1']
```